# best practice to define the same knockout extension for a huge list of model properties

Tags: knockout.js

I have knockout extension that I am using in the following way:

```
self.Id = ko.observable();
self.CompanyName = ko.observable().withUpdater("CompanyName", update);
self.Country = ko.observable().withUpdater("Country", update);
self.ContactFirstName = ko.observable().withUpdater("ContactFirstName", update);
self.ContactLastName = ko.observable().withUpdater("ContactLastName", update);
self.WorkPhone = ko.observable().withUpdater("WorkPhone", update);
self.MobilePhone = ko.observable().withUpdater("MobilePhone", update);
self.Email = ko.observable().withUpdater("Email", update);
...
```

I do not think that it matters what is withUpdater extension, because there could be also other extensions that rises the same q estion, but here it is:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.withUpdater = function (prop, handler) {
    var self = this;
    this.subscribe(handler.bind(this, prop, self));

    //support chaining 
    return this;

};
```

You see that there are a lot of properties that are defined in the same way. There are much more than in above code snipper.

I am looking for the best practise - is there a better way to define this (something like creating function that will loop through all model properties and add `withUpdater` for desired ones) or should I leave it as it is?

Comment: Can you post the withUpdater extension ?

Comment: I have posted withUpter.

Answer (score 2):

In this case would modify the withUpdater to avoid passing the observable name.

```
ko.subscribable.fn.withUpdater = function (handler) {
    var self = this;
    this.subscribe(handler);
    return this;    
};
```

So you can call it this way, which is less error prone.

```
self.CompanyName = ko.observable().withUpdater(update);
```

Comment: But how can I get obsrevable value inside handler then? I need observable value

Comment: @renathy if you want to get the observable remove the 'return this' in the withUpdater function.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if `update()` references the various observables, is to make it a `ko.computed`; then it will automatically subscribe to those observables. This works even if the `ko.computed` is used purely for side effects (e.g. sending data to the server) and never referenced directly.

Comment: update is updating given property with new value, so I didn't get you